# Can not create an organizational repository from a template with github API

Tags: github-api

I want to create an organizational repository with "internal" visibility (as it is the only way to create repositories in my org) in github but from a template.

So far I have been able to create an empty repository by doing the following: (*note the option 'visibility: internal'*)

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.github.com/orgs/MYORGANIZATION/repos' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 123123' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "repo-by-github-api",
    "description": "This is your first repository",
    "visibility": "internal"
}'
```

This returns 201.

Now when creating a repository from a template: (*note that there is no 'visibility: internal' option as it is not available*)

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.github.com/repos/Louis3797/awesome-readme-template/generate' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 123123' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "owner": "MYORGANIZATION",
    "name": "repo-by-github-api",
    "description": "This is your first repository"
}'
```

This returns 403 forbidden with a body that contains:

```
{
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "errors": [
        {
            ...
            "message": "MyGithubAccount123 cannot create a repository for MYORGANIZATION.",
            ...
}
```

The API token I'm using has all the permissions. I'm also following this documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-repository-using-a-template

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug, as there is no way to configure the visibility option?